# How to draw random numbers in a circle and a square?

Tags: r, statistics, plot

I want to visualize the the Algorithm of the Polar method from two perspectives (bird's-eye and frog's eye view).

To draw the first step of the method I need random number of the uniform distribution in a square and a circle.

I've already been able to plot the circle in a square, but how to plot random numbers (`z1`) inside of this construct?

```
require (plotrix)
require (grid)
z1 = runif (100)

plot (c(-1,1), c(-1,1), type="n", asp=1)
rect(-1,-1,1,1)
draw.circle (0,0,1)
```

And how to change the perspective?

Comment: what do you mean by "change the perspective"?  Can you point us to an existing example of what you're trying to achieve in R?

Comment: i want to see the distribution of the random numbers in the birds eye perspective like it is now, but also in the frog's eye view....how can I realise that?

Comment: Please be more precise about the definition of "frog's eye view".  It's hard to guess, and we shouldn't have to ...

Comment: I want to create random numbers of the normal distribution, beginning with random numbers of the uniform distribution by the polar method, a variation of the box muller algorithm. step by step you can see more from the well known density function of the normal distribution. So I want to see those steps from above like its now and from the front like a normal density function. hope you understand my problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do without 'rejecting' any points. The following R function needs `3*n` random numbers and will generate `n` randomly chosen points in a circle of radius `r`:

```
randp <- function(n = 1, r = 1) {
    if (n < 1 || r < 0) return(c())
    x <- rnorm(n)
    y <- rnorm(n)
    r <- r * sqrt(runif(n)/(x^2 + y^2))
    if (n == 1) U <- c(x, y)
    else        U <- cbind(r*x, r*y)
    return(U)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, or provide a reference?  I rewrote your formula, for a single element, as `xj = sqrt(unifj)* cos(thetaj)` . It's not clear to me that the square root of a uniform r.v. multiplied by the cosine of a sort-of normally distributed angle yields a uniform r.v.  .

Comment: Interesting. But I think throwing away the points outside the circle is faster: A (circle) = πr² = π; A (square) = a² = 4 Throwing away => needs to generate 4 / π pairs of uniform random numbers = 8 / π = ca. 2.55 random numbers per point < 3 random numbers per point. And normal random numbers take longer to generate than uniform ones (for me about 3 times as long).

Comment: @Carl This is mentioned somewhere in D. Knuth (1981). The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2: Seminumerical Algorithms, Chapt. 3: Random Numbers. I don't have it at hand right now. You may have a look at "Three Different Algorithms for Generating Uniformly Distributed Random Points on the N-Sphere" <www-alg.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/~jan/randsphere.pdf> for a reason why the normal distribution comes in.

Comment: @Hans-Werner: So it gets faster when the dimensionality grows. Good to know! Thx.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for the references.  Always fun to learn new things.

Comment: @HansWerner - +1, nice alternative. Had to improve my solution to still be faster ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To plot points, you need both x and y coordinates. ...But since your square is from -1 to 1, you also need to scale the points (or change the square):

```
x = runif(100, min=-1, max=1)
y = runif(100, min=-1, max=1)
points(x,y)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a function that generates random numbers on a circle. It uses rejection to discard points outside the circle. It uses an (in my opinion) interesting way to do so: It generates a batch of numbers, rejects some and then generates some more until enough values are available. This is typically much more efficient than generating one number at a time...

**UPDATE AGAIN** I improved the speed by not appending the new batch until the end. Also added speed comparisons.

```
rndCircle <- function(n = 100, r=1) {
    scale <- 1.15 # Generate 15% more values than requested
    m <- matrix(0, 0, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c('x','y')))
    lst <- list(m)
    nMore <- n
    while (nMore > 0) {
      #cat("nMore=", nMore, "\n") # uncomment to see how many iterations are needed

      m <- matrix(runif(floor(nMore*scale)*2, min=-1, max=1), ncol=2)
      m <- m[rowSums(m*m) <= 1, , drop=FALSE]
      nMore <- nMore - nrow(m)
      lst[[length(lst)+1L]] <- m
    }

    # Combine and truncate to desired length
    do.call(rbind, lst)[seq_len(n),]*r
}
# Measure performance
set.seed(42); system.time( rndCircle(1e6) ) # 0.19

# Compare to @Hans Werner's solution
set.seed(42); system.time( randp(1e6) )     # 0.26
```

Comment: how can I make the restriction that q=x^2+y^2 mustn't be 0 or >1, if that condition is false, new random numbers should be created like you posted?

Comment: @Tommy: you've just (sort of) reinvented one of the popular "rejection method" of generating random numbers from an arbitrary distribution function.  If you're interested, read things like "Numerical Recipes in C" chapter 7.3

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Well, I didn't reinvent it - I just reimplemented it ;-) Haven't read that particular chapter though.

Comment: Cool. You could also set `scale <- 4/pi` since that's the expected ratio of points in a square to points falling in the inscribed circle.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes, ...or even larger (1.5 or so) to (mostly) avoid looping.

Comment: @Tommy -- Yep, ... or even `scale <- n/(qbinom(p = 0.05, size = n, prob = pi/4))` if you want to require no second loop 95% of the time ;)

Comment: Why not just generate random polar co-ordinates and then convert to cartesian afterwards?

Comment: @James: because then you have to recognize that uniformly distributed thetas may not lead to uniformly distributed x and y coords.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not sure I understand the problem enough to see what that would be an issue, but how about using `y=runif(100,min=-sqrt(1-x^2),max=sqrt(1-x^2))` to constrain within the circle?